# KRE build executable of application

Tags: dnx

How do I build a stand alone executable for the "vNext" type of application?

My problem right now is that I have a console application of type Program.Main (not the service based one) and I want to build an executable out of this so that I could put it in the path and use it from the terminal.

I understand that "k run arguments" would do exactly that, but you would have to be in the project directory for this to work.

Edit - Progress: running `kpm build` on the directory with project.json will compile and produce a DLL. This DLL can be used as input to a hosting environment (working on that now)

Answer (score 0):

Actually k (which is now called dnx) is never intended to run as a standalone. It is prefixed like java or mono. This is by intention and will not vanish. Dnx is designed to not be centralized installed and therefore does not have kernel support which is necessary for a behavior like the requested one.

(I read somewhere that you might rename a copy of dnx but maybe I mix that up with corerun).